# How to pass data from one middleware to another middleware in ActixWeb

Tags: rust, middleware, actix-web

I can currently put data in the middleware and extract it in the request handler, using

```
req.extensions_mut().insert::<MyData>(my_data);
```

In the middleware, and then implement a `FromRequest` which uses something like this

```
let value = req.extensions().get::<MyData>().cloned();
```

Then I can have `MyData` in the request handler and this works.

But what I want to do is to have `MyData` added in `MiddlewareA` and then extract and use it in `MiddlewareB`.

I have tried using `req.extensions().get::<MyData>().cloned()` in the second middleware but it always return None.

So how do I achieve this?

Comment: Are you sure the middlewares are run in the expected order?